Movie with girl and old "innocent" assassin who killed her parents
WARNING! Spoilers ahead.
A girl is persecuted by an old man who killed her parents some years ago and is released from prison, but the man is innocent and only wants the girl confess her crime, but the girl kills him too. Does someone know the title of this movie?

Release year: 1978-84
Format: VHS
Country: UK


Any idea in what setting this was, or other details? One movie I'm thinking of is True Grit, which is set in the old Wild West.

^ The killer in True Grit wasn't innocent though.

+1 for including the plot, the ending, the timeframe and the country, which helped me (possibly) figure out what you're after, even if the question seems brief.

Sounds like you're looking for the UK thriller Schizo (AKA Amok AKA    Blood of the Undead) from 1976.

Samantha and Alan are getting married, but William Haskins isn't pleased. He grabs a train south to London and begins shadowing Samantha as she tries to get on with married life. Haskins' attempts to frighten her drive Samantha to desperation, but she's having trouble convincing anyone that she's being stalked. Even her psychiatrist dismisses her concerns as part of her neurosis. As bodies begin turning up, Samantha's story becomes more believable, and her dark secret from the past begins to reveal itself. 

In the end, the stalker is Samantha's uncle Bill, who went to jail for killing her mother. He finally confronts her and reminds her that she was the real murderer when she was still a kid and urges her to confess, but she kills him instead. The film is currently on Youtube. Here are some clips from it:



